# Align top imageView with the center of a relativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, view, android-relativelayout

how could set the layout parameters of the imageView in order to get something like this?[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: use Layout Top,bottom,right,left Margins to adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared a Simple Hack Solution.
Make a dump `View` and Assign your `View` Top to it.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/view1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Hope this could help you...Any Query are Welcome :)